# Behavior of a function near a singular point

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, singularity, singular-solution

What is the correct wording concerning the behavior of a function near a singular point? For example, the function $$f(x)=\frac{e^x+2}{x^2}$$ behaves like $2/x^2$ as $x$ approaches zero. Often, one is only interested at how fast it "explodes". So is it acceptable to say that "$f$ behaves like $1/x^2$ as $x$ approaches zero"? Or perhaps  "$f \sim 1/x^2$ as $x\rightarrow 0$"? I would like to "ditch" the constant because, in the manuscript I am writing, it makes the text unnecessarily complicated and the constant of proportionality has no importance. At least in my case.

Comment: "$f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $x=0$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use both

- asymptotic notation $f(x)\sim \frac1{x^2}$
- big O notation $f(x)= O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):
$$f\in\mathcal O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right) \text{ as } x\to 0.$$

Comment: Many compliments to you and @gimusi.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks. 